# Combining Two Saved Queries SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a lot of individual queries in SQL Server that I am hoping to combine via a master query.

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Query1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM Query2

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM Query3
```

It seems really basic, but I can't find the syntax to reference a query from another query.  There seem to be endless resources on creating subqueries and such, but combining all the queries into 1 master query is going to be very messy and unserviceable.  Is there a way to do this the way I am trying -- or do I have to rewrite everything to one gigantic query?

Comment: Can you create a view for the query?

Comment: This is unclear:  "I have a lot of individual queries in SQL Server".   What do you mean, you have "queries in SQL Server"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to do this. You only have to check that columns return by all of yours subqueries are identical. Here is a example.

```
    select * 
    from (select * from sys.dm_os_loaded_modules where description like '%WINRT%') as Q1 
    UNION ALL
    select * 
    from (select * from sys.dm_os_loaded_modules where description like '%RUNTIME%') as Q2
```

Comment: Running in this form returns the results from Query1 but not Query2

Comment: No, Q1 and Q2 are returned. I've just checked on my SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I'm going to focus on this line from it:

> but I can't find the syntax to reference a query from another query.

The closest thing to something like this that I know of is a CTE:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  paste query 1 here
), 
cte2 AS (
  paste query 2 here
), 
cte 3 AS (
  paste query 3 here
)
SELECT * FROM cte1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM cte2
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM cte3
```

Another approach that isn't really "referencing a query from a query", but might be what you want, would be to create a temp table or table variable, and insert the rows of each query into it, one at a time.   Then your "master query" would be to select all rows from the temp table/variable.

Comment: To take that a step further. You have access to all the CTEs in your final query. So you could do something like adding having a SELECT * FROM cte1 that references cte2 in its WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I figured out how to do it:

```
SELECT Query1.Stuff, Query1.MoreStuff, Query2.Stuff, Query3.Stuff

FROM (
Query1 SQL
) AS Query1

JOIN

(
Query2 SQL

) AS Query2

on Query1.key = Query2.key

JOIN

(
Query3 SQL
) AS Query3

on Query2.key = Query3.key
```